# How to grep against a huge .gz file fast?

Tags: performance, optimization, grep

A very simple grep question but looking forward tricks to improve the performance!

I am using the following code to grep a list of IDs in a file against the other huge compressed .gz file (~20G).

```
zcat my.gz | grep -wFf my.list > output.txt
```

Since this code would decompress .gz file first, then grep my list of 100k IDs against the decompressed file, it costs too much time!

Is there any way can process the job faster?

Thanks!

Comment: What about `zgrep`?

Comment: Yeh, seems better. Thanks!